# GPT partition deleted and unable to mount disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpt, testdisk

I accidentally deleted GPT partition table. Now I can't mount or see any data on my HDD. I tried every possible solution on internet instead it got worse. There is no back up.
On disks this is what it shows

[image]

When I run TestDisk it shows complete partitions and I am able to list all files.

[image: Deleted]

[image: Primary bootable]

[image: Primary]

I don't want to mess up any further. Is there anyway that I could mount my drive and its partitions?

**EDIT**
I can't remember what exactly I did to delete partitions as it was months ago.
I lost grub and tried to recover using `boot-repair` and `gdisk`.

So far I have tried `testdisk` `gpart`.

when I tried `sudo gpart /dev/sdb`, this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://www.simplified.guide/linux/disk-recover-partition-table, in particular the 'Quick Search' functionality within TestDisk.

Comment: If I select *Primary bootable it says Structure: Bad but for Primary and Logical its say Structure: OK

Comment: "_I accidentally deleted GPT partition table_" - Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/710073/edit) to tell us how you did this - it's important because there may be a backup of the partition table. "_I tried every possible solution on internet_" - What did you try? It's important that you tell us so we can (a) avoid telling you the same things, (b) identify how to undo this extra damage. _Do not reply here in the comments. Instead [edit] your question to include the detail._

Comment: @roaima I have edited my question.

Comment: If you "L" Load Backup what do you get?

Comment: If nothing works for you please give R-Studio Undelete a try: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000 it's IMO the best undelete program I've ever dealt with.

Comment: @roaima it says "No backup found!"

Comment: If able to list files in testdisk, be sure to back those up immediately. If you get further issues, you may lose the files. What does gdisk show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb` But seek error may mean you have drive issues. Back up then even more critical. Disks has the smartmon tools which may tell if drive is failing. https://askubuntu.com/questions/983619/s-m-a-r-t-data-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-16-04-disks-application or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools